# Make a button disappear based on user admin level

Tags: python, html, mysql, flask

I have to populate users in a table on a page.
I have successfully pulled users up from mySQL and correctly populated the table on html using {{users}}

However, based on the value of {{users.user_level}}, either 9(admin) or 1(normal user), I want to show an action button "Remove admin access" only if the admin level is 9.

I have tried to put the {{user.user_level}} into a variable and then use JavaScript to hide/show the button, but I cannot seem to map the value of user.user_level to the variable.

There might be an easier solution?

Controller:

```
    @app.route('/admin')
    def admin():
        mysql = connectToMySQL('advanced_login')
        result = mysql.query_db('SELECT * FROM users')
        return render_template('admin.html', users=result)
```

VIEWS:

```
    <table>
    <thead>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {%for user in users%}
        <tr>
            <td>{{user.id}}</td>
            <td>{{user.first_name}} {{user.last_name}}</td>
            <td>{{user.email}}</td>
            <td>{{user.user_level}}</td>
            <td><form action='/remove/{{user.id}}' method="POST">
                    <button>Remove user</button>
                </form>

                <form action='/change_access/{{user.id}}' 
                  method="POST">
                    <button>Remove admin access</button>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
        {%endfor%}
     </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually use an if else statement using `{% %}`. So in your case:

```
{% if user.user_level == 9 %}
    <form action='/remove/{{user.id}}' method="POST">
        <button>Remove admin access</button>
    </form>
{% else %}
    <form action='/remove/{{user.id}}' method="POST">
        <button>Remove user</button>
    </form>
{% endif %}
```